# Loading JList with components/values

Tags: java, swing

Can anyone tell me how I can insert some components/ values into `JList`? I 've being trying all means of loading my `JList` which can later-on be drag unto a textpane. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Sun has a [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) on their site that specifically covers using the `JList` component.

In its most simple form, you can create an array or `Vector` of "stuff" and pass it to the `JList` constructor. Each element from the array will be displayed.